# Javascript Diff Algorithm not working with HTML codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use [Javascript Diff Algorithm](https://johnresig.com/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/) to compare a text string input with a paragraph. This is my code.

HTML

```
<p id="db_structure">&lt;div class=&quot;myparent&quot;&gt;
            &lt;div&gt;
            &lt;div class=&quot;pdp-product-price test&quot; id=&quot;lll&quot;&gt;
            &lt;span&gt;650 rupees&lt;/span&gt;
            &lt;div class=&quot;origin-block&quot;&gt;
            &lt;span&gt;1,500 rupees&lt;/span&gt;
            &lt;span&gt;-57%&lt;/span&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;</p>
        <textarea name="new_structure" width="100"></textarea>
        <button id="compare">Compare</button></body>
```

and this is my js code.

```
$(function () {
                $.fn.diffString = function (txt) {
                    return this.each(function () {
                        $(this).html(diffString($(this).text(), txt));
                    });
                };

                $('#compare').click(function () {
                    var newstr = $("textarea[name=new_structure]").val();
                    $('#db_structure').diffString(newstr);
                });
            });
```

But if I input, `<div class="myparent"> <div> <div class="pdp-product-price test" id="lll"> <span>650 rupees</span>` it will show,

> 650 rupees <strike>`<div class="origin-block"> <span>1,500
>   rupees</span> <span>-57%</span> </div> </div> </div> </div>`</strike>

But the correct output should be

`<div class="myparent"> <div> <div class="pdp-product-price test" id="lll"> <span>650 rupees</span>`
 <strike>`<div class="origin-block"> <span>1,500 rupees</span> <span>-57%</span> </div> </div> </div> </div>`</strike>

Did I do anything wrong?

I logged the **diffString($(this).text(), txt)** inside **$.fn.diffString**.

code,

```
$.fn.diffString = function(txt){
    return this.each(function(){
        console.log(diffString($(this).text(), txt));

        $(this).html(diffString($(this).text(),txt));
    });
};
```

output,

```
    <div  class="myparent">  <div>  <div  class="pdp-product-price  test"  id="lll">  <span>650  rupees</span>
<del>&lt;div </del><del>class=&quot;origin-block&quot;&gt;
                </del><del>&lt;span&gt;1,500 </del><del>rupees&lt;/span&gt;
                </del><del>&lt;span&gt;-57%&lt;/span&gt;
            </del><del>&lt;/div&gt;
        </del><del>&lt;/div&gt;
    </del><del>&lt;/div&gt;
</del><del>&lt;/div&gt;
</del>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an alternative way. Unfortunately it included changing the plugin. I found this code from this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/Z3CRA/1/). And here in the plugin code we have to change,

inside **diffString()** function,

change,

```
str += " " + out.n[i].text + nSpace[i] + pre;
```

to,

```
str += " " + escape(out.n[i].text) + nSpace[i] + pre;
```

Hope someone else will find it usefull